# Job Applications under Messages on Careers listing not all job applications

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I go to the Careers website, then to Messages and Job Applications, I see only one job application that I sent off. However, I sent off at least 3.

This is either a bug, or I don't understand where I am supposed to find the applications that I've submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a server migration over the weekend which paused the processing of background services, so some tasks were delayed. We should be all caught up now.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Everything seems to be working as expected now!